# Best way to store chrome.storage profiles

Tags: google-chrome-extension

*OK. Perhaps not **best** but believe that might be a better title for search engines.*

Using `chrome.storage` to save profiles, typically as in:

```
chrome.storage.sync.save(
    { 
        profiles: [
            {
                id : profile1,
                foo : 42,
                bar : 2.71828
            }, {
                id : profile2,
                foo : 3.14,
                bar : 1.618033
            }, …
        ],
        current_profile : 'profile2'
    }
);
```

There is some issues with this.

For one I have to update *entire* ***profiles*** on each save from my *options* page. I can not say *save `profile[32]`* but have to say *save `profiles`*. Though one need to have rather huge profile settings and a lot of them for it to be an issue, I do not like the *forced* bad style.

I could save each profile in root, but that feels like as using `x^n` public `var`'s in Ecma.

This brings up some issues when it comes to using these values in content scripts as well.

1. Request storage from background script.
2. Background script receive request and do asynchronous lookup.
3. On response report result back to content script.

If I choose a model where I store each profile at root, and not as an array, I would have to do the above ***asynchronously*** in several separate rounds. First get *current_profile*, have a callback function that then request that key, and a third callback function reporting back to initiator with result. That is ugly complex and result in loads of extra code.

As of now I save *current_profile_id* holding the id and *current_profile* holding a duplicate of the entry in the profiles array so that I can request *current* in content script, but this as well is ugly as it forces a dupe at root level only for request.

On each level storage is retrieved, synced or updated the complexity, and more importantly, redundancy, is a factor a bit to high.

Am I missing something in the design process here. Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: I don't really see a problem in calling a callback in a callback's callback. It is all nice and asynchronous, so what is the problem ? _"It is ugly, comlex and results on loads of etra code"_: 1. If you DRY up your code the _"extra code"_ you refer to is no more than a couple of lines (which is negligible). 2. I don't see the complexity here (especially since you have already worked this out). 3. I don't find it ugly - I find it cute (not to mention how asynchronously cool it is to call a callback in a callbac's callback) !

Comment: BTW you can access `chrome.storage` right from the context of a content-script, so you don't have to send a message to the background-page to do it for you.